# How to set format of DTPicker in vb6?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
<code>
private sub save_click()
SQL = SQL + "DATE_OF_BIRTH=('" & TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DTPicker1.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")) & "'),"
end sub
</code>
```

It is showing error like: sub or function not defined.
    please help

Comment: Did you define the sub or function `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`?

Comment: First print the values returned by SQL and see if the statement is correct

Comment: No I didn't defined sub/function,because I thought it's a built-in function....... and this statement is working at sql prompt but gives error at vb6 application....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SQL = SQL & "DATE_OF_BIRTH between " & Format(DTPicker1(count).value, "DD-MM-YYYY") & " and " & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, DTPicker1(count).value), "DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

At least that's how I do it for MSSQL and Postgresql